# How to store files with JS?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I want to store images and sounds using JS. Is there any API for this, like the localstorage? Unfortunatly in the localstorage I can only save text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you could store files manually (with Google Chrome's [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-system-api/)), the intended approach is caching. Cache is a straightforward way to store your media seemingly *automatically*.

It's only a matter of writing a manifest:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
blast.ogg
styles.css
images/gun.png
```

After the first load of these files, you just load them again as usual, but they come from the disk instead of your server. It works when the browser is off-line, too.

It also degrades nicely: unsupported browsers would simply manage the cache as they see feet.

Here's [a tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/) by Google at HTML5Rocks.

Answer (score 1):

You have no access to the local filesystem via JavaScript in a browser. This is due to the sandboxing and is a major feature of the security model inside a browser.

Regarding `localStorage`, you may store just text, but with the help of `JSON.stringify()` and  `JSON.parse()` you can store almost any object or data you come across in JavaScript.

Comment: But when I opened this site: https://skid.gamagio.com/play/ The google chrome asked me, if I allow to store data on my computer.

Comment: I can't load  the link you give right now, but i think this probably refers to [indexdb](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/IndexedDB). But imo the support here is not widespread enough for practical use - take a look at [here](http://caniuse.com/#search=indexeddb).

Comment: if you combine it with web sql database, you can support all major browsers except IE.  But i'm feeling generous, that's why no -1 ( :-p )

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible to [base64](http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-base64.html) encode files and then save them to localStorage. You can find more information on encoding and saving images [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/blogs/bobleah/entry/html5_code_example_store_images_using_localstorage57?lang=en).